# How to make git bash directory string format the same as cmd?

Tags: bash, git, cmd

For example, when I open up `git bash` on my desktop, it shows:

```
John@DESKTOP-PLOS3KB MINGW64 ~/Desktop

$ (heres where I enter my command)
```

`cmd` shows:

`C:\Users\John\Desktop> (heres where I enter my command)`

---

I want it so that `bash` will show the same `directory header` as `cmd` does, in the same format. Is this possible? I don't want like `username@computer-name MINGW64...`. How can I change it so that it shows what `cmd` does?

**I am running a windows machine**

Thank you

Comment: This is the reverse of what you ask. You did tag it CMD despite in not being a CMD question in any way. `Prompt %username%@%computername% CMD.exe $_ $$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prompt is controlled with the PS1 variable. You can set it like:

```
PS1='${PWD}> '
```

to have it print the full current working directory instead of the abbreviated one that you get as part of the default prompt. Compare with

```
PS1='\w> '
```

which abbreviates `$HOME` to `~` and trims it to the maximum length set in `$PROMPT_DIRTRIM`